# Azure Blob Storage: Why limit the Single Blob Upload Threshhold

Tags: azure-storage

Is there any reason not to set the SingleBlobPutThresholdInBytes property (from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.cloudblobclient.singleblobuploadthresholdinbytes.aspx)) to anything more than 1MB (the minimum)?  It seems to me that the 32MB default is dramatically high.

Isn't it ideal to always upload in parallel when you're trying to send files that are 1MB or larger?  Why would you want a higher threshhold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually depends on your scenario. In case you want to make less number of requests to Windows Azure Storage, [Put Blob](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179451.aspx) can upload a block blob in one single request.

Comment: If I want to increase parallelism, I want to set the `SingleBlobPutThresholdInBytes` value as low as possible, to increase performance for smaller files.  I agree that if I wanted to throttle the requests, the REST API would work, but then this setting doesn't come into play (since this setting is from the CloudBlobClient, not the REST API).  The question is:  *Why use the CloudBlobClient with a high threshhold?*

Comment: When the blob size is smaller than SingleBlobPutThresholdInBytes, the Azure Storage Client Library will make use of this REST API. Hence, if your goal is to make a single HTTP request to upload a single blob, then this property is useful.

Comment: OK, so setting that value higher allows you to make fewer requests to Azure storage.  Makes sense. Thanks.